# Banana Pi memory bus clock speed

Tags: hardware, memory

I hope this is not too off-topic but I think you are the people that may most likely got their hand on a Banana Pi board and can answer my question.

- What is the memory clock speed of the DDR3 RAM on the Banana Pi?

I did quite some research on the Web but couldn't find some source indicating the transfer speed/bus clock of the DDR3 RAM that is built into the Banana Pi. The board uses an Allwinner A20 SoC, just as, for example, the Cubieboard 2. This one apparently runs at 480MHz bus clock speed so I wonder if there is a technical reason that would imply the same speed for the Banana Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default clock speed was 480MHz, but in recent releases it's been reduced to 432MHz to address some stability issues. See this page for more info: http://forum.lemaker.org/2066-1-1-all_images_has_update_to_a_new_version_.html.